# setState not updating soon enough to update my view

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I am very new to React and recently migrated from Angular. I have found updating state of a variable not fast enough using setState to reflect in my render(). I want to display a loader as soon as user clicks the button and hide it as soon as he closes it. However the loading icon is not displayed as soon as I clicked it and there is a slight delay in display because of asynchronous behavior of setState(). Is there any work around for it.

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state= {
     displayExportLoading: false
  }
}
download() {
    this.setState({ displayExportLoading: true});

    // async actions of fetching and rendering elements

    // promise is complete

    Promise.all(options)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({displayExportLoading:false});
      }) 
}
render() {  
      var loadingOnExport = this.state.displayExportLoading? <img src= {loaderExport} width="30px"/>:''

     return(
       <button onClick={this.download}>Download</button>
       <div>
        {loadingOnExport}
       </div>
     ) 
}
```

I want to display the loader image as soon as I click the button not with slight delay. Can this be achieve without state variable?

Edit 1:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state= {
     displayExportLoading: false
  }
}
download() {
    this.setState({ displayExportLoading: true});
    var pageCount;
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm");
    var pos = 20;
    var gapBetweenImages= 40;
     metrics = metrics.map(async (key, index) => {
      let id_val = `graph-id-${index}`; // creating IDs
      const input = document.getElementById(id_val);
      // html to pdf
      let canvas = await html2canvas(input,[1300,1300]);
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG");
      var imgWidth =canvas.width / 8;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      if(index % 2== 0 && index !== 0) {
          pos = 20;
        doc.addPage();
      }
      if( index %2 == 1) {
            pos = imgHeight  + gapBetweenImages;
      }
      doc.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 15, pos, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    //   doc.addPage();
      console.log("image data",imgData)
      pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    });
    Promise.all(metrics)
      .then(() => {
        doc.deletePage(pageCount);
        doc.save("file.pdf");
        this.setState({ displayExportLoading: false })

      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

}
render() {  
      var loadingOnExport = this.state.displayExportLoading? <img src= {loaderExport} width="30px"/>:''

     return(
       <button onClick={this.download}>Download</button>
       <div>
        {loadingOnExport}
       </div>
     ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following by taking advantage of the setState() callback (2nd argument) to only begin your additional processing after `displayExportLoading` has been set to `true`. From the documentation for [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

```
download() {
    this.setState({ displayExportLoading: true }, () => {
      // async actions of fetching and rendering elements
      // promise is complete

      Promise.all(options)
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({displayExportLoading:false});
        })
      }); 
}
```

Another option could be using CSS [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) to show/hide the `<img />` instead of adding/removing it from the DOM:

```
render() {
     const { displayExportLoading } = this.state;

     return (
       <button onClick={this.download}>Download</button>
       <div style={{ visibility: displayExportLoading ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
         <img src={loaderExport} width="30px" />
       </div>
 );
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Its still taking some pause.

Comment: You are rendering an `<img />` tag that needs to load something from a `src` value. That obviously can take some amount of time to render/load.

Comment: I think this doesn't solve it. The callback just guarantees that the state update is really applied. It's not changing "how fast" the state update happens so the delay is still the same.

Comment: Can we load the image somehow when the component loads and not display it?

Comment: Sure. You can use CSS to hide the image instead using `visibility` for example to avoid adding/removing it from DOM.

Comment: I tried using a div tag in place of img, and that too isn't loading. Surely it isn't related to loading issue i guess

Comment: you can add a delay using `setTimeout` just to show the loader.

Comment: @udggog I updated the answer to show an example of using CSS visibility as a possible option to avoid adding/removing from DOM and hopefully help with the load time as the image would be able to load in the background.

Comment: I tried, not working. Its has to do with setState since when I console above and below the setState() function I am getting the consoles right but not the state value which means there has been a delay in state change

Comment: @PranayTripathi the loader ideally should show when I call the function download() since the first line itself is changing the state

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, without a working example this is difficult to provide assistance. `this.setState({ displayExportLoading: true});` should absolutely not take 3 seconds to execute so you have potentially other issues happening.

Comment: is the `src` in the `image` tag an external link or an image from your file system ?

Comment: from my asset folder. Its a small gif of 82 kb

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Update the question. Its the jsPDF that is creating the issue. Any suggestion to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your `download` method based on the comments explaining what you're trying to accomplish:

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...

  download = () => {
    this.setState({ displayExportLoading: true }, () => {
      // this will change the state immediately, 
      // show the loading indicator,
      // then run the rest of code, before setting `loading` back to `false`

      let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm')

      const createMetric = async (key, index) => {
        let pageCount;
        let pos = 20;
        let gapBetweenImage = 40

        // ...

        let canvas = await html2canvas(input, [1300, 1300])

        // ...

        return { pos, pageCount, gapBetweenImages }
      }
      const handleCreatedMetrics = (createdMatrics) => {
        createdMetrics.forEach(metric => {
          // example `matric` object: { pos: 1, pageCount: 2, gapBetweenImages: 3 }
          doc.deletePage(metric.pageCount)
          doc.save('file.pdf')
        })
      }
      const resetLoadingState = () => {
        this.setState({ displayExportLoading: false })
      }

      const metrics = [1, 2, 3, 4] // using some dummy values

      Promise.all(metrics.map(
        (item, index) => createMetric(item, index) // pass whatever you need here
      ))
        .then(handleCreatedMatrics)
        .then(resetLoadingState)
        .catch(handleStateAppropriately)
    })
  }

  render() { 
    const loadingOnExport = this.state.displayExportLoading
      ? 'Loading!'
      : ''

    // don't forget to use a `fragment` if you're 
    // not wrapping elements inside of a `div`
    return (
      <>
        <button {...} />
        <div>{loadingOnExport}</div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

In the example above, I am returning an object for each metric with the relevant information (`pos`, `pageCount`, & `gapBetweenImages`) so that you can do the rest of necessary actions inside of the `handleCreatedMetrics` after all promises are resolved.

This should change your state immediately and show the `loading` indicator when that happens, then change the state back to `false` so that you can display the appropriate results.

---

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do with the `pageCount` after each call, so you might want to adjust my example slightly for your needs.

For example, if you need to call `doc.deletePage` for each `metric.pageCount`, but call `doc.save('file.pdf')` at the end, you might want to do this instead:

```js
download = () => {
  // ...

  const handleCreatedMetrics = (createdMetrics) => {
    createdMetrics.forEach(metric => {
      doc.deletePage(metric.pageCount)
    })
  }
  const saveDocument = () => {
    doc.save('file.pdf')
  }

  Promise.all(...)
    .then(handleCreatedMetrics)
    .then(saveDocument)
    .then(resetLoadingState)
    .catch(handleErrorAppropriately)
}
```

You should be able to take this, however, and adjust it to your needs.

---

Example `CodeSandbox` that I've used for testing:

- [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-surf-wuvpf?fontsize=14)

Comment: I tried this solution. For any other operation with setTimeout its working fine, just not for these particular libs of html2canvas and jspdf

Comment: What if you wrap the `Promise.all()` inside of a `setTimeout`, so that it runs after X amount of seconds, so it shouldn't be blocking the main thread and `loading` should show immediately... Kinda hacky but might do the trick - `setTimeout((() => { Promise.all(...) }, 1000)` - wait for 1 second before doing the `html2canvas` and `jspdf` related stuff

Comment: What I did to get the result is put all the Loops and promise operations inside a set time out method. Only the setSate() is kept outside. It gives time for the loader to set.